# Is 64-bit mandatory condition for iOS 8 submit to App Store

Tags: app-store, 64-bit, ios8

As iOS 8 will be released this month and my app is only support 32-bit(because a 3rd lib only compatible for 32-bit), I'm not sure the new version of my app whether will be rejected if I submit it to App Store on next month, because it does not support 64-bit.

Need I set my app support 64-bit(replace the 3rd lib) before I submit updates?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As long as You do not include **Extensions** inside Your app bundle, You can submit 32bit apps. I don't know if I can quote from developer.apple site/forum so I leave it as comment.

Answer (score 1):

Right now - you can submit 32-bit apps.
We have successfully submitted our 32-bit app to the App Store almost a month ago and planning to submit an update (also 32-bit) in the near future.

But Apple will [require](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a) the apps and updates to be 64-bit starting February 1, 2015.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st February only counts for new Apps. Existing Apps have until June. And I'm sorry I can't find the source anymore where I read that.